# Is this valid to do? (c, c++, java)

Tags: java, c++, c, while-loop, do-while

```
void loop()
{
    if (button || tilt)
    {
        do
        {  
            while (ss.available()>0)
            {
                char c = byte(ss.read());
                if (gps.encode(c)) 
                {    
                    if (gps.location.isValid()) //I want this to run until this function is true 
                    {
                        Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6); 
                        Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6); 
                    }
                }   
             }
        } while (gps.location.isValid());
    }
}
```

The above code is from arduino, but i post here because this is not a question about the arduino, but about programming in C style languages.

I want to succesfully reach the Serial.print() part. I have put a do while loop to ensure this runs continuously.

Now, my question is, is this valid?
My intention is to run until gps.location.isValid() returns true. But gps.location.isValid() is calculated inside the do while loop and i also have it as a condition ON the do while loop.

I mean, while (gps.location.isValid()); will try to recalculate this function, or if the function IN the loop returned true, then the value will be "remembered" and thus i will exit the loop?

Or even if it managed to return true inside the loop, the while (gps.location.isValid()); will try to rerun this function, or it will remembered it passed it before?

My aim is when gps.location.isValid() returns true, to do the following commands and exit. NOT try to calculate and run it twice (one inside the loop and one in the condition).

Because in my program, it will never pass it twice, thus it will run forever. I want to pass it one time, execute the two statements and end.

Comment: You seem confused, I suggest you take 1/2-1 day break and you will get it right yourself :) I mean it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is one way:

```
void loop()
{
    if (button || tilt)
    {
        bool isGpsLocationValid = false;
        while (!isGpsLocationValid)
            {
                while(ss.available()<=0)
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // wait for 1 sec
                }
                char c = byte(ss.read());
                if (gps.encode(c)) 
                {    
                    if (gps.location.isValid())  
                    {
                        Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6); 
                        Serial.print(gps.location.lng(), 6); 

                        isGpsLocationValid = true;
                    }
                }   
             }

    }
}
```

**Update:**

The `sleep` in the inner while loop waits for at least one second (configurable). If you want to be deterministic about the wait then you may want to check spin lock implementation in that language's library, or some other mechanism.

In the code you posted, `gps.location.isValid()` at end of outer do-while loop the will be calculated even if has been calculated inside the inner loop.

Comment: This would also terminate if `ss.available() == 0` even if `gps.location.isValid()` is still `false`.

Comment: T.C is right. I want to retry the loop if ss.available==0. I want to retry until i for sure pass the gps.location.isValid().

Comment: Also, in my first example, is the gps.location.isValid() calculated both times, or only one.